# PlayOneShot audio - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity and C# game developers I need your help.

I have tried adding audio in my game. I'm using PlayOneShot and the sound output is ok. Should I press key W, my plane moves upwards and should change sound, which is different from the one when plane is moving forward. Now here's the bug, it kind of seems to repeat the sound should the key W be pressed. It sounds, well, bad. How can I get it such that I can play the sound without being repeated, in a way that it doesn't affect the plane moving up continuously?

I have tried using th following code:

```
using UnityEngine;

private AudioSource audioSourceGoingUp;
bool isKeyWHeld = false;

private void Start()
{
    audioSourceGoingUp = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        //Some_other_code_is_here
        if (!isKeyWHeld)
        {
            audioSourceGoingUp.PlayOneShot(raptorGoungUpSound);
            isKeyWHeld = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isKeyWHeld = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well arguably every other frame its going to play the one shot while W key is down, is this what you intended?

Comment: Yes @BugFinder . I need it such that the audio doesn't repeat continuously. I really need key W to host the two functions - Going up and playing the audio one time and not on repeat mode.

Comment: so rather than a boolean of yes/no you need to know if the sound played more than x ago....